# FPGA booting from a specified address in a SPI Flash

Tags: fpga, spi, lattice

I am working with lattice crosslink-nx fpga. Recently I had a requirement where I need to boot fpga bitstream from an external SPI flash. But the Bitstream is located in a random address (which is a known address). So in this scenario, can I boot my fpga from that particular location of SPI ?. (Note : I am using Lattice Radiant Software and lattice crosslink-nx evaluation kit)

I actually tried searching source material for this problem. But I only found out about dual booting method which is not what I expected.